# Python Module Printing

Tags: python

My functions are printing when they are run, but I want to either print from my master file or create a separate print function. I don't know how to pass the return value to my print.

Master.py:

```
import main
import split
import password
```

main.py:

```
import split

def main():

  #  first_name = raw_input('please enter Your Name: ')
  #  family_name = raw_input('Please enter Your Surname: ')
  #  student_ID = raw_input('Please enter your Student ID number: ')

    first_name = 'Benjamin'
    family_name = 'Montgomery'
    student_ID = '1000036317'

    login = split.letters(first_name, family_name, student_ID)
    print login  
    return login

main()
```

split.py:

```
# import main

def letters(first_name,family_name,student_ID):
    name = first_name[:3]
    lastname = family_name[:3]
    ID_tree = student_ID[:3]
    login = name+lastname+ID_tree
    #   print login
    return str(login)

# letters(first_name,family_name,student_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your functions look ok, but be careful about creating modules that share the same names with common functions and methods. "split" is a method of string. I tested out your code with minor changes and it printed fine (here's what I got):

> login -> BenMon100

```
#msplit.py
def letters(first_name,family_name,student_ID):
    name = first_name[:3]
    lastname = family_name[:3]
    ID_tree = student_ID[:3]
    login = name+lastname+ID_tree
    #   print login
    return str(login)

#main.py
import msplit

def main():

#  first_name = raw_input('please enter Your Name: ')
#  family_name = raw_input('Please enter Your Surname: ')
#  student_ID = raw_input('Please enter your Student ID number: ')

    first_name = 'Benjamin'
    family_name = 'Montgomery'
    student_ID = '1000036317'
    login = msplit.letters(first_name, family_name, student_ID)
    print 'login ->', login
    return login

main()
```

Comment: my first time posting somehow it only posted half my thing :(

Comment: @BenjamindeMontgomery use the `edit` link under your question to edit your post. Next time, please examine the preview below the compose box to make sure your post looks good.

Comment: mt teacher told me something very similar Your functions look ok, but be careful about creating modules that share the same names with common functions and methods. "split" is a method of string. I tested out your code with minor changes and it printed fine (here's what I got):

Comment: well still i cant work out what to do sitting here, wishing for a solution. i did try to repost it im not sure were it went, im gonna go and look for it now.